# Use Access to Import XML File, Update then Output the Same XML file

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

I have an XML File that I want to input into MSAccess update some of the elements and then export the same XML File with the updates.

I created an XSL File to Transform the Parent / Child relationship into a flat file but that only showed me the  /  entry in the MSAccess file Import

Can you point me in a direction to research how I can Import and Export the same file Using MSAccess and or SQL.

XML Data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="CD-Catalog-New2.xsl"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <years>
      <year>1985</year>
      <year>1986</year>
      <year>1987</year>
    </years>
  </cd>
    ETC.
```

The XSL Code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Country</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Company</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Price</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Year1</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Year2</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Year3</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="country"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="company"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
      <xsl:for-each select="years/year">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image: Access XML Import]

As you can surmise I am very new at this XML, XSL etc.
Over 70 but can still learn.
Help would be appreciated

Comment: Access has intrinsic tools for import/export xml. The xml does have to be properly structured. Or code can read/write xml file as a text file object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Access VBA to export to XML with headings for various records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659881/how-do-i-use-access-vba-to-export-to-xml-with-headings-for-various-records)

Comment: Got it to work in Access with your help, Thank, You