# How to export and format an XML for records?

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, export

I'm working on VBA code to export each record from a specific query to a single XML file.
Each XML file will have 'one' record from the MS Access query and the destination where each XML file will be saved is different for each record output found in the query.
In the query, there is one value that will have the detailed path, where the record should be saved. Therefore the loop will be able to save each XML file to the destination based on each record read.

I have my 'temp' XML Export. (I've replaced the data from each value to 'valueName_here' for purposes of this example, but on each value, those values vary.):

'temp' xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
<qryWMC0302a>
<WMCID>18</WMCID>
<ID>176068</ID>
<Title>Title_here</Title>
<TitleSupp>TitleSupp_Here</TitleSupp>
<Date>Date_Here</Date>
<Cast>leadPerformer_here|leadPerformer_here|leadPerformer_here|leadPerformer_here|etc|</Director>
<Overview>Overview_Here</Overview>
<Tagline>Tagline_Here</Tagline>
<Duration>duration_here</Duration>
<StudioID>StudioID_ID</StudioID>
<DataProviderID>DataProviderID_here</DataProviderID>
<MPAARatingID>MPAARatingID_Here</MPAARatingID>
<Rating>Rating_Here</Rating>
<ProviderRating>ProviderRating_Here</ProviderRating>
<MasterTableID>MasterTableID_Here</MasterTableID>
<Studio>studio_here</Studio>
<DataProvider>DataProvider_Here</DataProvider>
<MPAARating>MPAARating_Here</MPAARating>
<PathID01>PathID01_Here</PathID01>
<PathID02>PathID02_Here</PathID02>
<Path03>Path03_Here</Path03>
<Path>Path</Path>
<Pth01LkUp>Pth01LkUp_Here</Pth01LkUp>
<Pth02LkUp>00\Pth02LkUp_Here</Pth02LkUp>
<XMLID>XMLID_Here</XMLID>
<MovieVideo_TS>MovieVideo_TS_here</MovieVideo_TS>
<XMLsmallCoverParams>Path\To\File\Here</XMLsmallCoverParams>
<XMLlargeCoverParams>Path\To\File\Here</XMLlargeCoverParams>
<Folder>Path\To\File\Here</Folder>
<FolderL>Path\To\File\Here</FolderL>
<Chk>Chk_here</Chk>
</qryWMC0302a>
</dataroot>
```

The goal is for the final xml file to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<METADATA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <NeedsAttribution>true</NeedsAttribution>
  <DvdId>
  </DvdId>
  <MDR-DVD>
    <MetadataExpires>Expiration_Date_And_Time_Here</MetadataExpires>
    <Version>Verion_Number_Here</Version>
    <leadPerformer>leadPerformer_here|leadPerformer_here|leadPerformer_here|leadPerformer_here|etc|</leadPerformer>
    <director>director_Here | director_Here, etc</director>
    <dvdTitle>dvdTitle_here</dvdTitle>
    <MPAARating>MPAARating_Here</MPAARating>
    <dataProvider>dataProvider_here</dataProvider>
    <releaseDate>releaseDate_here</releaseDate>
    <duration>duration_here</duration>
    <genre>genre_here|genre_here|etc</genre>
    <XMLsmallCoverParams>Path\To\File\Here</XMLsmallCoverParams>
    <XMLlargeCoverParams>Path\To\File\Here</XMLlargeCoverParams>
    <studio>studio_here</studio>
    <title>
      <titleNum>Number_Here</titleNum>
      <titleTitle>titleTitle_here</titleTitle>
      <synopsis>Details of the record-film will be here.</synopsis>
      <leadPerformer>leadPerformer_here|leadPerformer_here|leadPerformer_here|leadPerformer_here|etc|</leadPerformer>
      <director>director_Here | director_Here, etc</director>
      <providerRating>providerRating_here</providerRating>
      <studio>studio_here</studio>
      <MPAARating>MPAARating_Here</MPAARating>
      <communityRating>communityRating_here</communityRating>
    </title>
  </MDR-DVD>
</METADATA>
```

In the 'temp' xml output there are additional values that are not needed in the 'final' xml file; however, some of the 'additional' values are needed in the VBA loop to know the 'name' of the xml final file (each 'final' xml file will always have a different name) as well as the path where the 'final' xml file is to be exported to (each 'final' xml file will be exported to a different location\path)

I tried to adapt answers to a working xsl (XSLT stylesheet) that will copy the needed elements from my 'temp' xml file to a 'final' properly formatted xml file, as seen in the example posted here.
The closest I found: [How do I use Access VBA to export to XML with headings for various records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659881/how-do-i-use-access-vba-to-export-to-xml-with-headings-for-various-records).

How do I post a xsl template to take the input from the 'temp' xml output and copy to the 'final' xml file?

Comment: Could you provide a real sample of the 'temp' and 'final', as it isn't clear what the field mappings are. eg you have leadPerformer twice in the 'final'? where does <director> come from? why is the <title> a sub element?

Answer (score 0):

I followed to the letter the information found in the following link:

The documentation can be found in the following link: https://support.ptc.com/help/wnc/r11.2.0.0/en/index.html#page/Windchill_Help_Center/WCCG_BusLogicCust_WorkPackage_XMLTrnsfmSample.html

On that link it is decribed in detail each field that is needed to go from a 'temp' to a 'final' file

Cheers!