# How to add xml and xml-stylesheet nodes to an XML file in VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, xslt

I'm using Access VBA to create an XML file.

```
Dim dDokument As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set dDokument = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Dim environmentalDataNode As IXMLDOMElement
Set environmentalDataNode = dDokument.createElement("mainnode")

'...Adding some stuff

Call dDokument.save("c:\Temp\test.xml")
```

This writes a fine XML file, except I have to have these two lines at the beginning of my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="https://secure.umweltbundesamt.at/h2o/xml/uba_schnittstellen.xslt"?>
```

They are not written when I use the code above.

So, how do I add XML and xml-stylesheet nodes to my DOMDocument60?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use Access VBA to export to XML with headings for various records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659881/how-do-i-use-access-vba-to-export-to-xml-with-headings-for-various-records)

Comment: no, it does not.

Comment: I think is does. Did you try? Also, your posted code fails for `dDokument.createElement("main node")`.

Comment: What I am seeing is need for xslt file. Here is another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67071835/vba-with-xslt-to-pretty-print-xml-with-end-tags-in-the-same-line

Comment: You think that I have to create and load a xslt-file? It would be a lot easier to load the result as text, add the two lines to the string and save it.

Comment: Yes, text read/write is an option.

Comment: It is an option, but this cant be the one to go for. Its more like a dirty workaround Ill only use when there is no (easy) way to do it with DOMDocument60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="https://secure.umweltbundesamt.at/h2o/xml/uba_schnittstellen.xslt"?>` is a processing instruction you can create with e.g. `Set pi = dDokument.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=""text/xsl"" href=""https://secure.umweltbundesamt.at/h2o/xml/uba_schnittstellen.xslt""")` (I hope I have the correct VB syntax for escaping the double quotes and the assigment) and then insert with e.g. `dDokument.insertBefore(pi, dDocument.documentElement)`.

The first item you have shown is the XML declaration. It is usually not created with DOM methods as a node but rather added during serialization/saving of the document tree, like done by the `save` method. Don't you get an XML declaration added (with the default encoding UTF-8) by your use of `save()` at the end?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms755439(v=vs.85) suggests that the XML declaration, though technically not being a processing instruction, in the context of the MSXML APIs, can nevertheless be created with `Set dec = dDocument.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""")` (and of course be inserted with `dDocument.insertBefore(dec, dDocument.firstChild)`).

Comment: It worked fine. The xml-declaration was not added on save. Maybe there is a easier way to add this, but until then I use your solution.